# Add Attribute stopWithTask="true" to <service /> in android manifest xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to cleanup resources and stop services if my app is swiped up and closed. In that case normal `onDestroy()` LifeCycle events are not fired. Through a little bit of search I found out I need to override `onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)` method and add `stopWithTask="true"` to the service in the manifest.

But how do I add the `stopWithTask="true"` attribute in `<service />` to the final generated manifest via Xamarin Visual Studio? `[Service]` attributes specified above c# classes don't have the `stopWithTask` property. They only have the `Exported`, `Name`, `IsIsolated`, `Icon` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can just call `StopSelf()` in the `OnTaskRemoved()` method which will effectively do the same thing as `android:stopWithTask="true"`.

Sadly the `android:stopWithTask` item is not documented well. If you look at the main syntax of `Service`, you should see this item from the top:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

However it is barely documented in the `FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK` item:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo.html#FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK

Which links to:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#stopWithTask

I would personally use the first method instead of this attribute as it's not documented that well on Android's side.

Comment: Based on my test we need to return `START_NOT_STICKY` in `onStartCommand` with `stopSelf()` in `OnTaskRemoved`